# Add a variable to a batch process

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, batch, script

I'm using `ffmpeg` to rip some video files. I am looking to rip each video to a size of about `500 MB`. To achieve this, I need the option to enter the video bitrate I choose for each individual file.

This is the batch file I am currently using:

```
ffmpeg -i "%%g" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1400k -vf "scale=720:-2" -c:a copy "converted\%%~ng.mp4"
```

I would like to do something similar to this, but I am having a difficult time determining what to write:

```
ffmpeg -i "%%g" -c:v libx264 -b:v %variable%k -vf "scale=720:-2" -c:a copy "converted\%%~ng.mp4"
```

If anyone is aware of an option in `ffmpeg`, that would be great, but I could also plug this into a script to get it to work if that would be easier.

Thank you so much for the assistance!

Comment: Sort of. I use the method in the link to compress all videos to a specific preset bitrate, final file size does not matter. This method is used to create a file of a specific size (500MB in this case). I have a simple method to calculate the bitrate I need, but I would like a batch file that will allow me to input that bitrate for each file.And yes, I've had way too much time to think over the past couple months and video compression has become my obsession. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry somebadhat, I honestly didn't even think about this until today. BTW, that method you sent me to run 2-pass encodes over multiple video files is working to perfection!!! Thank you again! Also, for this, I only run a single pass (quality isn't as critical). File size is the top priority in this case.

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: You are right. Posted a new one asking about including the bitrate determination in the ffmpeg process. Also added an additional variable, different audio tracks (some are 128k and others 384k)

Comment: where is it? link

Comment: You need: bitrate = 500 / duration.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1551546/encode-command-that-will-result-in-a-specified-file-size   correct, bitrate = 500 / duration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMD batch ffmpeg process video: Rescale, crop, and remux all .mkv and .mp4 in directory. **Makes a directory named** converted. Process video to .mp4
Add extensions to `'dir *.mp4 *.mkv /A-D /B'` i.e. `'dir *.mp4 *.mkv *.mv4 /A-D /B'`
Does not work on sub-directories.
User input: Video bitrate, crop top, and crop bottom.
Test mode or process entire video.
[How to write a batch file](https://superuser.com/search?tab=votes&q=%20%5Bbatch%5D%20closed%3Ano%20for%20move)

You might want to download, install and use [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/rotation.php?file=HandBrake-1.3.2-x86_64-Win_GUI.exe) for Windows 64-bit and [WinFF](https://winff.en.lo4d.com/download/mirror-hs1) to learn what settings to use.

Windows users use NUL instead of /dev/null and ^ instead of \
Non-Windows users use /dev/null instead of NUL and \  instead of ^

```
@echo off 
ECHO. 
ECHO What video bitrate do you want to encode at?
SET /p zrate="Enter = 700 or Your own number: "
IF /i not defined zrate SET zrate=700 
ECHO How many pixels do you want to crop from the top? 
SET /p ztop="Enter = 0 or Your own number: "
IF /i not defined ztop SET ztop=0
ECHO How many pixels do you want to crop from the bottom? 
SET /p zbottom="Enter = 0 or Your own number: "
IF /i not defined zbottom SET zbottom=0
if not exist converted (md converted)
for /f %%g in ('dir *.mp4 *.mkv /A-D /B 2^>nul') do (
rem process entire video
rem ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%%g" -crf 20.0 -vcodec libx264 -b:v %zrate%k -vf scale=768:432,crop=iw-0-0:ih-%ztop%-%zbottom%:0:%ztop% -preset veryfast -c:a copy "converted\%%~ng.mp4" 
rem process second 0 through 6
ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%%g" -crf 20.0 -vcodec libx264 -b:v %zrate%k -vf scale=768:432,crop=iw-0-0:ih-%ztop%-%zbottom%:0:%ztop% -preset veryfast -c:a copy -t 00:00:06 "converted\%%~ng.mp4"
)
exit /b
```

Crop 150px of the top:

```
"ffmpeg.exe" -y -i "%%g" -crf 20.0 -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=768:432,crop=iw-0-0:ih-150-0:0:150
```

Crop 150px of the bottom:

```
"ffmpeg.exe" -y -i "%%g" -crf 20.0 -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=768:432,crop=iw-0-0:ih-0-150:0:0
```

Process video from second 300 to second 320:

```
"ffmpeg.exe" -ss 00:05:00 -y -i "1.mkv" -t 00:00:20 "2.mkv"
```

Bing search - [ffmpeg remux](https://www.bing.com/search?&q=ffmpeg+remux)

Bing search - [ffmpeg rescale](https://www.bing.com/search?&q=ffmpeg+rescale)

Bing search - [ffmpeg crop](https://www.bing.com/search?&q=ffmpeg+crop)

Comment: I'm back to see if your expertise can help me yet again. I'm working with some new videos that require cropping to get rid of the bars on top/bottom of the screen. The bars vary in size so I need to add another variable to your command. Here is what I added: "crop=in_w:in_h-%zcrop%,scale=720:-2", which works fine with a predefined bitrate, but I need a command that allows me to input both the video bitrate and #of pixels I need cropped (%zcrop%). When I run the bat file I would like it to ask for both #'s for the bitrate & the pixels to be cropped. Your expertise is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here's the ffmpeg command I am looking to set the bitrate (zrate) and pixels to be cropped (zcrop): ffmpeg -i "%%g" -c:v libx264 -b:v %zrate%k -vf "crop=in_w:in_h-%zcrop%,scale=720:-2" -preset veryfast -c:a copy "converted\%%~ng.mp4

Comment: If you reduce the size of your player do the bars disappear? Create a google drive account and upload a 10 second sample video. https://drive.google.com