# Encode command that will result in a specified file size

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am looking to create a batch file that will take a video file (either MP4 or MKV) and compress it to an MP4 file that will result in a specific size.

Something like this where the video bitrate is automatically adjusted to result in the final file being ~500MB.

There will be an additional variable in the equation as the video files have one of two audio bitrates. One runs 128k and the other 384k.

```
ffmpeg -i "%%g" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1400k -vf "scale=720:-2" -c:a copy "converted\%%~ng.mp4"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert / encode a video to a size of your choice, with an audio bitrate of your choice by calculating the duration of the video and the video bitrate needed to achieve that size:

Test output is 15 second 1280x720 h264 video aac audio .mp4 in folder \converted
Final output is full length 1280x720 h264 video aac audio .mp4 in folder \converted
See `rem test`
`:zmath` works but is inelegant.

You want a 500MB video and the length is 5 minutes 20 seconds. If you want an audio bitrate of 128Kb then video bitrate should be:

```
((500000KB * 8) / 320s) - 128Kbits
(200.000/320)-128= 497Kbits
```

Why "size * 8"? because size is in Bytes and bitrate is in bits (1byte=8bits).

How to determine what video bitrate to encode by (input size / calculated duration) - (input audio bitrate) using cmd, set /p, for, ffprobe, set /a, and encode using [ffmpeg](https://techbeasts.com/fmpeg-commands):

Add to `dir *.mkv *.mp4`. Change `rem test`. Change? output to `converted` folder.

```
@rem Convert / encode a video to a size of your choice, with an audio bitrate of your choice by calculating the duration of the video and the video bitrate needed to achieve that size:
@rem https://superuser.com/a/1551554/1003800
@rem Windows 10 64-bit 051420
@echo off 
ECHO. 
ECHO What audio rate do you want in Kb?
SET /p zaudio="Default 128 or enter your own number "
IF /i not defined zaudio SET zaudio=128 
ECHO. 
ECHO What file size do you want in MB?
SET /p zsize="Default 500 or enter your own number "
IF /i not defined zsize SET zsize=500 
for /F "eol=; delims=" %%g in ('dir *.mkv *.mp4 /A-D /B 2^>nul') do ( 
for /F "delims=" %%h in ('ffprobe.exe -v error -show_entries format^=duration -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 "%%g" 2^>^&1') do set "zduration=%%h"
echo. 
echo Duration is %zduration% seconds. 
rem set z 
rem pause 
Call :zmath
if not exist converted md converted
echo. 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem test
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -y -i "%%g" -crf 20.0 -vcodec libx264 -b:v !zvideo! -filter:v scale=1280:720 -preset slow -acodec aac -ar 48000 -b:a !zaudio! -async 48000 -t 00:00:15 "converted\%%~ng.mp4"
rem ffmpeg -i "%%g" -crf 20.0 -vcodec libx264 -b:v !zvideo! -filter:v scale=1280:720 -preset slow -acodec aac -ar 48000 -b:a !zaudio! -async 48000 "converted\%%~ng.mp4"
rem production
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
rem Begin restore variables for next run 
rem remove k from zaudio
set zaudio=%zaudio:~,-1%
rem restore zsize to MB
set /a zsize=zsize/1000
set zvideo=
rem   End restore variables for next run
)
exit /b 

:zmath
rem begin convert MB to Kb
set /a zsize=zsize * 1000
rem   end convert MB to Kb
set /a zvideo=((zsize * 8 / zduration) - zaudio) / 1
rem begin remove trailing whitespace and append letter k on zaudio
set /a zaudio=zaudio/1
set zaudio=%zaudio%k
rem    end remove trailing whitespace and append letter k on zaudio
rem set z 
rem pause 
exit /b
```

See https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=407

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40102931/8826818

See https://www.google.com/search?&q=windows+10+cmd+set+%2Fa+missing+operator

See [List of Useful FFMPEG Commands for Video & Audio Editing](http://dfellows.rf.gd/files/ffmpeg1.html) html

See [List of Useful FFMPEG Commands for Video & Audio Editing](http://dfellows.rf.gd/files/techbeasts.com-List-of-useful-FFMPEG-Commands-for-Video-Audio-Editing.pdf) print friendly 500k .pdf

See [List of useful FFMPEG Commands for Video & Audio Editing](https://techbeasts.com/fmpeg-commands) at techbeasts.com:

Comment: Thank you again!!!

Comment: @olp improved answer.